# SharePoint form mapped to columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, flow

We currently have a SharePoint environment which works as follows:

We have a document library which contains project propositions.
Project propositions being a content type I made based on the document set. So, the document sets may contain various stuff related to the project proposition, but each contains, by default, a form which is actually a PDF file with fields mapped to SharePoint columns. The form has text, date and number fields, and has tables which can calculate totals.

This pdf part, with fields mapped to SharePoint columns was made possible by an application called PDFSF (https://www.pdfsfcloud.com/). However, we have now experienced to many problems with the application (fields staying empty and even the whole app being down sometimes) and I must now find an alternative.

Project propositions can then enter an approval workflow (with Microsoft Flow) on demand. Then being approved by certain people, in order.

Essentially, the document sets part being nice to group stuff together, but not a priority, all we really need is a document/form (whatever the file format) with fields somehow linked to SharePoint columns of its content type (or whatever else), somehow calculate totals in it, and enter an approval workflow. A document/form which we can also print and easily share.

ANY tips, ideas, or other apps for SharePoint you know could do this well, would be appreciated. As I am picking this project up and I am not very experienced with SharePoint ( yet ; ) ).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If things are as dire as your question to the community suggests, I recommend that you use an InfoPath Forms Library.  You can still use Flow in this  library type in SharePoint Online.

Review these two links:

1. [Microsoft: create a form library for your content type](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-a-sharepoint-library-or-site-content-type-for-your-form-template-ae137cab-bad4-42f0-8105-34f6b1430a70)
2. [Creating the form first and creating the library based upon the fields in the form.](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2121642&seqNum=8)

Be sure to enable attachments in the library and the form.  That’s how your users will be able to associate additional documents to the proposal (i.e.: project proposal).